# robots.txt and Google spyware

Tags: robots.txt, spy

On my web page I have robots.txt in which I specified some pages that I don't want google to index. 
Chrome and Google toolbar sends information about pages that I have visited.

I read somewhere that google will index sites  which I blocked in robots.txt.
Is that true?
Where can I read more about it?

Comment: http://www.tgdaily.com/security-features/39176-chrome-is-a-security-nightmare-indexes-your-bank-accounts  an old article, but I dont think google changed this, They could only better hide what they are doing

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.ineedhits.com/tips-advice/why-google-can-index-your-robotstxt-blocked-urls-12346715.html

It seems it wasnt google chrome or toolbar who crawled sites. The problem was that there exists extern links on sites that are blocked.